# Help Request time is running out to connect to links

Tags: configuration

Good morning Gentelman, and sorry for my english. I write you because my experience with Tor: I have download tor then I tried to connect me with some link of the hidden wiki, but the connection faild because of time is running up: that’s exactly what is wroten: Tempo per la connessione esaurito

Il server sta impiegando troppo tempo a rispondere.

> Il sito potrebbe essere non disponibile o sovraccarico. Riprovare fra qualche istante.
>
> Se non è possibile caricare alcuna pagina, controllare la connessione di rete del computer.
>
> Se il computer o la rete sono protetti da un firewall o un proxy, assicurarsi che Tor Browser abbia i permessi per accedere al Web

According to https://deepl.com the text translates to:

> The site may be unavailable or overloaded. Please try again in a few
>   moments.
>
> If no pages can be loaded, check your computer's network connection.
>
> If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make
>   sure that Tor Browser has permissions to access the Web

Thank You for you helping me if it is possible.

Michele.

Comment: Have you tried to modify the "Network Proxy" settings under "Preferences"?

Comment: in wichh way can I do it, please? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

On the upper right of the Tor Browser click on the 3 small horizontal bars, select "Preferences", on the bottom of the new window under "Network Proxy" click on "Settings" and you will get to the "Network settings/proxy settings for internet access" (Impostazioni di connessione/Configurazione dei proxy per l'accesso a internet).